# Send mail from SQL: permission denied

Tags: sql-server, email, triggers

I have a trigger like this:

```
ALTER trigger [dbo].[TR_AlertOnConnection]
on [dbo].[Log]
with execute as owner
for insert
```

In the trigger, the sp_send_dbmail is called to send an email. When a row is insterted in the table, I get an error:

```
The EXECUTE permission was denied on the object 'sp_send_dbmail', database 'msdb', schema 'dbo'.
```

I understand that I the user must be a member of DatabaseMailUserRole in order to send mail. But... since I execute the trigger "as owner", which user I have to put in this group?

Comment: I would recommend not sending emails from within your trigger in the first place. I would suggest creating a staging table for emails and inserting to that table in your trigger. Then create a sql job that reads the staging table on a set interval and sends out the email. You don't want to hold up normal processing of every insert while you wait for an email to be sent.

Comment: It's not a problem since an insert happens rarely, and even more rarely an email is sent. The problem here is authorization, can you help me?